# how can i update the data dynamically after some time using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

suppose the response is coming from the server when i hit the GET request as:

#### API response

```
[
{
  id: 1
  status: "Pending",
  startedAt: "10:30",
  endsAt: "12:30"
},
 {
  id: 2
  status: "Pending",
  startedAt: "11:30",
  endsAt: "1:30"
 },
....
]
```

now i want to change this status field after every 1 hour to **Started** and then **Finished**

how can i do this using node.js and what should be the correct implementation for doing this.

Comment: You can run a Cron Job every hour at Backend if new entries are being added continuously.

Comment: If you want to change this data on your database, maybe you should use a cron Job library, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: what about using `setInterval` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cron job` .

Step 1) `npm i crontab --save`

Step 2) `npm i node-cron --save`

Now in your `index.js` or inide your `main` js file of node . Wirte the following command .

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const crontab = require('node-crontab');

crontab.scheduleJob("0 * * * * " , function(){
     //do something cool    
},{
    schedule: true,
    timezone: "Asia/kolkata"
});
```

The above function will run at every 1 hour and you can do your code inside that . 


For more information , Go through the [official Document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) for performing the operation after a specific interval.

```
var yourData = [
  {
    id: 1
    status: "Pending",
    startedAt: "10:30",
    endsAt: "12:30"
  },
   {
    id: 2
    status: "Pending",
    startedAt: "11:30",
    endsAt: "1:30"
   },
  ....
  ]
async function updateData(){
  //Call your API and update the data
  yourData = await yourAPICall()
}

setInterval(updateData, 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Comment: will this function call after every specific time or it runs only once.

Comment: @Ravi this will call `updateData` every 1 hour = 3600000 ms.

Comment: @Ravi you can check with `setInterval(() => console.log(new Date()), 5000)`